# barryvdh/laravel-dompdf - How to add javascript and/or jquery code into PDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf

Thank you in advance

I am generating PDF with `barryvdh/laravel-dompdf` laravel library, i am able to add dynamic code to add in PDF but how to add javascript or jquery code

I tried like this

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('invoice', compact('invoiceDetails'));
$pdf->setOptions(['enable_javascript', true])->setOptions(['javascript-delay', 13500])->save(public_path('invoice.pdf'));
```

invoice.blade.php looks like this (Just adding small code)

```
<h2 class="h2">Summary<span id="demo_span"></span> </h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
       document.getElementById('demo_span').innerHTML ='THIS IS FOR AN EXAMPLE';
</script>
```

So the output would add text "THIS IS FOR AN EXAMPLE" where ID is `demo_span`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
You have to set it in the package settings. Publish the config and change
it there.

To make it work, you need to use this JS bloc inside your PDF Blade :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> try { this.print(); } catch (e) { window.onload = window.print; } </script>
```